# How to use sqlite3 session extension with ruby

Tags: ruby, sqlite, rubygems

I'd like to make use of the SQLite3 session extension (https://sqlite.org/sessionintro.html) under Ruby using the sqlite3 gem, but can't figure out how to do that.  Can anyone give me guidance on how to proceed?

(I'm currently using FreeBSD and have compiled sqlite3 with the SESSION extension.)

Comment: The question is pretty vague. Can you share an example of what you have tried so far? Are you getting errors? etc

Comment: You'll need to check (and possibly rebuild) SQLite for the extensions, and Ruby is unlikely to provide bindings for the `sqlite3session_*` functions, so you'll likely have to write the bindings yourself.

Comment: I don't know how to start - I can't figure that out from the sqlite3 gem documentation.  As I stated, I have compiled SQLite3 for the session extension, but how this gets accessed by the sqlite3 gem is unclear to me.

Comment: The session functions are not (yet) part of that gem; you have to extend that package, or write your own.

Comment: OK - not the answer I wanted, but at least I won't waste time looking for something that doesn't exist.  Any idea on how to get started extending the gem?